# appending a json file with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an existing json file (data.json) that I would like to append with information captured from a form.

I have the form outputting json but I am not sure how to go about getting this to add to my existing json file.

So the form looks like this:

```
<form id="test" action="#" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="department">Department:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="department" id="department" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="role">Role title:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="role" id="role" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pay_status">Pay status:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="pay_status" id="pay_status"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="typicalposts">Typical number of posts in a year:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="typicalposts" id="typicalposts"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Restrictions:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="restrictions" id="restrictions" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recruitment_date">Recruitment date:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="recruitment_date" id="recruitment_date" />
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="weblink">Weblink:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="weblink" id="weblink" />
</div>
<div class="text-center">
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary center_block" />
</p>
</div>
</form> 
<pre id="output" ></pre>
```

And the js I have to turn this data to json is:

```
(function() {
function toJSONString( form ) {
var obj = {};
var elements = form.querySelectorAll( "input, select, textarea" );
for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
  var element = elements[i];
  var name = element.name;
  var value = element.value;

  if( name ) {
    obj[ name ] = value;
  }
}

return JSON.stringify( obj );
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var form = document.getElementById( "test" );
var output = document.getElementById( "output" );
form.addEventListener( "submit", function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var json = toJSONString( this );
  output.innerHTML = json;

}, false);

});

})();
```

This shows the json in #output for the moment, I would like what is being shown here to be appended to data.json instead

Thanks for your help

Comment: use ajax and a server side language

Answer (score 1):

> My files are hosted on a server that I dont have access too which is why I would like to do this via js

So BBC News have an HTML document at `http://www.bbc.co.uk/news`. Would it be a good idea if it was possible for my browser to edit the page and save it back to the server?

It is absolutely impossible to do what you want, because it would require that any old browser could edit any old file on any old server.

In order to change data on the server, you have to have the cooperation of the server (which you say you don't have).

Comment: Sorry I have worded that wrong, it is my web platform and my json file. But the content management system we use doesnt allow me to use backend languages

Comment: @GaryBurton — If you can't run code on the server to change the file, then you can't change the file.

Comment: Ok thanks for this. Im going to try and get this to work on my local machine and then figure out getting access to the server later. What would you recommend to get it working locally?

Comment: @GaryBurton — The same. You need a local server and some server side code. (Which comes down to a combination of "What is your favourite programming language?" and "What does the production server I'm going to have to use support?")